# Why does python (mysql.connector) always return 1 when using "@row_number"

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

versions:

- Python: 3.10.2
- MySQL: 5.7
- MySQL Workbench: 8.0

I am building a webapp and stranded on a problem, MySQL doesn't give the expected result if I use mysql.connector in python to execute my query. So the situation is as follows:

[image: Class table]

I want too rank the students by grade with the ROW_NUMBER function, since MySQL doesn't support the ROW_NUMBER function there is a work around. The (working) MySQL statement is:

```html
SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE WHEN @Class = Class THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END AS Rank, 
    Name,
    @Class = Class,
    Grade
FROM
ORDER BY Class, Grade DESC
```

If I run this in MySQL Workbench it runs fine. No problem whatsoever, When I run this using python and MySQL.connector the "Rank" column always returns "1". As if python doesn't accept MySQL parameters in the query. Here is my python code:

```
cnxn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql = "QUERY ABOVE"
cursor.execute(sql)
records = cursor.fetchall()
for row in records:
    print(row[0]) #every result is 1
```

Does anyone has a solution for this? Or at least an idea of what the problem might be? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You should do the ordering in a subquery, not the same query that uses `@row_number`.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x you can use window functions instead of `@row_number`

Comment: I upgraded the server and I can use window functions now. Thank you.